# Use Procedure and Trigger to update a table

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb, procedure

I have a database that stores some information about TV Series.

This database has a table called `Stagione` with the column `Anno` (YEAR).

I need, for each row of `Stagione`, to declare a variable `differenza` that stores the difference between `Anno` and `YEAR(GETDATE())`, and if the value of `differenza` is < 10:

```
UPDATE Stagione.Prezzo = Stagione.Prezzo * 0.9
```

I don't know how to combine a trigger and a procedure to make this happen, is this possible?

I work on phpmyadmin 10.1.13-MariaDB

EDIT, now work:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE Promoz (IN an YEAR)
BEGIN
DECLARE differenza YEAR;
UPDATE stagione
SET Prezzo = prezzo*0.9
WHERE (an-Anno > 0) AND (an-Anno < 10);
UPDATE stagione
SET Prezzo = 0
WHERE (an-Anno > 10);
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please show the structure of your table. Maybe you can give the `CREATE TABLE` statement you have for `Stagione`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update the records now, you will have the desired result, but only now. Because if you query the same data three years later, you'll still find records where `Prezzo` was multiplied with 0.9, but in the meantime have an `Anno` that is more than 10 years ago.

Instead, you should just leave the data as it is, and work with a database view that does the calculation at the moment of the query. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Stagione_view AS
SELECT Anno, 
       YEAR(GETDATE()) - Anno AS differenza,
       (CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - Anno < 10 
            THEN 0.9 ELSE 1 
       END) * Prezzo AS Prezzo
FROM   Stagione
```

Now, just make sure you always query `Stagione_view` and not `Stagione`, and you'll have the desired effect.

#### Explanation of the code

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`: this creates a new object in your database: a view. Just like a table it has rows and columns. The difference is that its data is retrieved dynamically from other table(s) with a `SELECT` statement. So when you query the view, the database will actually perform that `SELECT` statement in the background.

`YEAR(GETDATE()) - Anno AS differenza`: this is the calculation of the year difference. Because it is done in a view, this will always be accurate, using the current value of `GETDATE()`.

Then the magic part:

```
CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - Anno < 10 
     THEN 0.9 ELSE 1 
END
```

This will check if the year difference is less than 10. If so a value of 0.9 is taken, else a value of 1. This result is then used in the larger expression:

```
       (CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - Anno < 10 
            THEN 0.9 ELSE 1 
       END) * Prezzo AS Prezzo
```

... that 0.9 or 1 is multiplied with `Prezzo`. Of course, if the first value is 1, then this just results in the same value as `Prezzo` already had, but other wise you are doing `0.9 * Prezzo`. Whichever it is, it is given the name `Prezzo` in the view. So when you query the view you will see the adjusted `Prezzo` value:

```
SELECT * FROM Stagione_view;
```

#### After rephrasing of Question

> every first day of the year, check the difference between `Stagione.Anno` and the current year, if this difference is lower than 10 and upper than 0 update `Prezzo=Prezzo*0.9` else set `Prezzo = 0`

In that case issue the following `update` statement on the first day of the year:

```
UPDATE Stagiane
SET    Prezzo = CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - Anno < 10 
            THEN 0.9 ELSE 0 
       END) * Prezzo
WHERE  YEAR(GETDATE()) > Anno
```

You can schedule this statement to be executed with the [`CREATE EVENT` statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/events/).

For instance:

```
CREATE EVENT adjust_prezzo
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR
STARTS '2017-01-01 08:00'
DO 
    UPDATE Stagiane
    SET    Prezzo = CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - Anno < 10 
                THEN 0.9 ELSE 0 
           END) * Prezzo
    WHERE  YEAR(GETDATE()) > Anno;
```

Comment: I understand what you mean and you're right, but i can't understand what your code do. I' m a beginner but i really want to learn, can you explain me? Thank you

Comment: I seen this now, and i'm going to try

Comment: Sorry, but my bad english created problems. Probably I have not explained well. What I want to do is, every first day of the year, check the difference between Stagione.Anno and the current year, if this difference is lower than 10 and upper than 0 update Prezzo=Prezzo*0.9 else set Prezzo = 0.

Comment: I updated the answer based on this comment. I suppose you do not want to change the value when `Anno = YEAR(GETDATE())`.